# How do I load an html file according to a route in sammy js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sammy.js

I don't have enough experience with javascript and jQuery development so I was wondering if someone could tell me how to create a function that uses sammy.js and HTML templating.

This is the working code I have right now:

```
<script>
    ;(function($) {

      var app = $.sammy(function() {

        this.get('#/', function() { $('#content').text(''); });

        this.get('#/home', function() { $('#content').load('main.html'); });

      });

      $(function() { app.run() });

    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

This code puts the `main.html`'s content when I go to or click on `...html#/home` but I am looking for a javascript function that just figures out the end point of the URL (the word after `..#/` ) and gets the html page of that same name.

In [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode):

```
if( somethingWasClicked and uses sammy.js )
  loadContent();

function loadContent() {
    endpoint = figureOutEndPoint();
    $('#content').load(endpoint.html);
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need a [route with a parameter](http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes) in it:

```
this.get('#/:page', function() { 
    $('#content').load(this.params['page'] + '.html');
});
```

Make sure that's after your other routes or it will get called for almost everything (such as `#/home` which you're already handling).

You can, of course, put other parameters in the routes:

```
this.get('#/:where/:is/:pancakes/:house', function() {
    // Do things with this.params['where'], this.params['is'],
    // this.params['pancakes'], and this.params['house'].
});
```

You just need to make sure you get the order right or the routes can fight each other. Routes are matched in the same order that they're added in so the more general catch-all routes usually go at the bottom.

Comment: @Kartik: Can't let you have a bad time with Sammy.js, that's one of my favorite JavaScript libraries :)

Comment: hi, for some reason when I directly go to `...html/#info` where info isnt the default page.. it doesnt seem to load info.html unless I specifically click on a link on the page to the `#/info` page. Is that suppose to happen? doesnt sammy.js support this linking?

Comment: @Kartik: Is sammy set up on every page?

Comment: well im just talking about the same page. I have sammy.js installed on index.html and the menu has the links to various other pages where all the links in the menu are in the form `#/pagename` and according to the rule from your answer everything works fine. For example when info link on menu is clicked = `#/info` the contents of info.html get displayed perfectly.But if I copy the url to `index.html#/info` and paste the url into a new tab.. it doesnt display the info content

Comment: I see. The problem is that when the browser sees `index.html#/info`, it will load the `index.html` page and there's nothing that Sammy can do about that; then, when `index.html` is loaded, Sammy can do its thing with `#/info`. There's nothing that Sammy (or any other JavaScript) can do about that unless you hooked up click handlers all over the place and Sammy won't do that (nor, IMHO, should it). Just use `#/info` style URLs in your links.

Comment: Actually, I figured out what was wrong, I had a onload function in the body tag and it would run on every refresh. I removed it and now it works normal

Comment: @muistooshort let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1965/discussion-between-kartik-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: @crunkchitis: I actually use `pancakes` instead of `foo` :)